# Javascript changing pictures

Tags: javascript

So I used two images and `setInterval` to change two pictures continuously over time. When I click on the picture, I will use `clearInterval` to freeze the image. My question is how do I make the two images change continuously again when I click on it? So it's like a on and off like of scenario. Below is the code which makes the two pictures change continuously and when I click on it, the image freezes and do not change between themselves.

```
var imageArray = ["_images/korea.jpg","_images/images.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
function changeImage(){
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}
var test = setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
myImage.onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(test);
}
```

Comment: Have some boolean value, set it outside of `onclick`. In `onclick`, branch on that value so you know which thing to call set or clear, then flip the bool to the opposite value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `clearInterval`, use `Boolean` `flag` and `invert` it on click of the `image`

```js
var imageArray = ["_images/korea.jpg", "_images/images.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var flag = true;

function changeImage() {
  if (flag) {
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
      imageIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}
setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
myImage.onclick = function() {
  flag = !flag;
}
```

**Or** you can re-initiate `setInterval`

```js
var imageArray = ["_images/korea.jpg", "_images/images.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var interval;
var clicked = false;

function changeImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}
interval = setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
myImage.onclick = function() {
  if (!clicked) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clicked = true;
  } else {
    interval = setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
    clicked = false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean variable to decide if you are going to change the image. Set or reset this boolean variable when you click on the image without clearing the interval.

```
var active = true;

myImage.onclick = function(){
   active = !active;
}


function changeImage(){

    if (!active)
       return;

    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :)

```
<img src="img1.png" id="cimg" onclick="trigger()">
<script>
var imageArray = ["img1.png","img2.png"];
var imageobject = document.getElementById("cimg");
var imagecount = -1;
var changable = true;
function changeimage() {
imagecount++
if(imagecount < imageArray.length) {
imageobject.src = imageArray[imagecount];
}
else {
imagecount = -1;
}
}

function loop() {
if(changable) {
changeimage();
setTimeout(function() { loop(); },1000)
}
}
loop();

function trigger() {
if(changable) {
changable = false;
}
else {
changable = true;
loop();
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is different to the others because it clears the timer, as opposed to just checking if the flag is set. Your changeImage action stays the same.

```
var flag = false, timer;
function changeAction() {
    if (flag) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        timer = setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
    }
    flag = !flag;
}
changeAction();
myImage.onclick = changeAction;
```